# Forcing LiveData to behave synchronously

Tags: android, android-room, android-livedata

I have some queries on my Room DAO that I need to use sometimes synchronously in a background thread, other times asynchronously on MainThread returning a LiveData.

Currently I do two versions of the same query:

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM Entity")
abstract fun list(): LiveData<List<Entity>>

@Query("SELECT * FROM Entity")
abstract fun listNow(): List<Entity>
```

Is there a way to force the first method to behave synchronously so I don't need two equal queries?

Comment: what kind of solutions are you open to? RX, Coroutines?

Comment: The first method was designed explicitly to not be synchronous. What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: Have just one method for both async and sync operations, some libraries have some methods to permit both (like Objectify use `.now()` for Google Datastore and coroutines use `.await()`). I read the class of LiveData and there is no method to force a syncronous operation to happen.

Answer (score 0):

**Few notes**

First, `Room` does not allow synchronous queries outside the box.

Next, the architecture / design of the `Room` is really meant for asynchronous calls since these queries are not meant to be fetched instantly.

> Room ensures that Database is never accessed on the main thread because it may lock the main thread and trigger an ANR. If you need to access the database from the main thread, you should always use async alternatives or manually move the call to a background thread.

**What you can do**

You can allow it via explicitly calling `allowMainThreadQueries` when setting up your database.

**References**

- https://developer.android.com/reference/android/arch/persistence/room/RoomDatabase.Builder#allowMainThreadQueries()

Comment: I will not access the method in the MainThread, i will access in another thread, like in a custom DataSource implementation or in the SyncService. On those, I will want the method to return a List on the MainThread I want the method to return a LiveData.

Comment: Based on your use case, does your project currently have RxJava2 in place?

Comment: It does have, not with Room.